# Jetty and SQLite connection in servlets

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets, jetty, database-connection

I'm making a small servlet app in Java, with Maven, in Netbeans. I'm using SQLite database, and newest Jetty server. I have problem with creating connection pool for use in servlets. What works(in servlet):

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:c:\\db\\base";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

And this works without specific settings in jetty.xml/web.xml/pom.xml
I have libraries to use SQLite and connection pools (org.xerial.sqlite-jdbc, commons-pool, commons-dbcp).

What doesn't work:

web.xml:

```
    <resource-ref>
       <description>DB Connection Pool</description>
       <res-ref-name>jdbc/DSTestPool</res-ref-name>
       <res-type>javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource</res-type>
       <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

jetty.xml

```
<New id="DSTestPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTestPool</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">org.sqlite.JDBC</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:sqlite:c:\\db\\base</Set>         
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

pom.xml - dependencies.

This configuration, even without changes in code (change to using pool) creates error in jetty console:
`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
....
Caused by:
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nothing to bind for name jdbc/DSTestPool at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusDescriptorProcessor.bindEntry(PlusDescriptorProcessor.java:895)
...`

Opening app in Jetty: Error 503

I think there is something wrong with my declaration of jdbc/DSTestPool in jetty.xml, I've tried different parameters, but result was the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is one parameter missing in your jetty.xml, you can declare any of the following types:

- **org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.EnvEntry**: for env-entry type of entries
- **org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource**: for all other type of resources
- **org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Transaction**: for a JTA manager
- **org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Link**: for link between a web.xml resource name and a naming entry

And each of these types follow the same pattern:

```
<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.xxxx">
  <Arg><!-- scope --></Arg>
  <Arg><!-- name --></Arg>
  <Arg><!-- value --></Arg>
</New>
```

Your jetty.xml file have the name and value but the scope is missing.
Try with the following for JVM instance scope (the name is unique across the JVM instance)

```
<New id="DSTestPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg><!-- empty arg -->
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTestPool</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="driverClassName">org.sqlite.JDBC</Set>
            <Set name="url">jdbc:sqlite:c:\\db\\base</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Or something like the following for a web app context scope (the name is unique to the WebAppContext instance)

```
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <New id="DSTestPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
        <Arg><Ref refid='wac'/></Arg><!-- reference to WebAppContext -->
        <Arg>jdbc/DSTestPool</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPoolDataSource">
                <Set name="driverClassName">org.sqlite.JDBC</Set>
                <Set name="url">jdbc:sqlite:c:\\db\\base</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </New>
</Configure>
```

See the documentation [here](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/using-jetty-jndi.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

An approach could be to use HikariCp (or any other pooler..). 
In jetty-env.xml:

```
<Configure  class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
 <Arg></Arg>
 <Arg>jdbc/ds</Arg>
 <Arg>
   <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
     <Arg>
        <New class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
           <Set name="dataSourceClassName">org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource</Set>
           <Call name="addDataSourceProperty">
              <Arg>url</Arg>
              <Arg>jdbc:sqlite:path/to/test.db</Arg>
           </Call>
        </New>
     </Arg>
  </New>
</Arg>
```

In web.xml:

```
<resource-ref id="ds">
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/ds</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

then you get datasource:

```
(DataSource)new InitialContext().lookup("java:/comp/env/jdbc/ds");
...
```